# Saving form information with sessions

Tags: php, forms, session

I'm trying to use sessions to save form input, but it works only on the last form submitted.

I have an index.php that goes like this:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['number-of-sessions'] = 0; ?>
...
```

then, there's a link to form.php:

```
 ...
  <form action='display.php' method='post'>
     <input type='text' name='name'/>
     <input type='text' name='id'/>
     <input type='submit' value="Submit"/>
 ...
```

And here's display.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['number-of-sessions']++;
    $_SESSION[$_SESSION['number-of-sessions']] = $_POST;
?>
...
<?php
    for($i = 1; $i <= $_SESSION['number-of-sessions']; $i++) {
        print_r($_SESSION[$i]));
    }
?>
// another link that goes back to form.php
```

So basically, it always prints the last form submitted and the others are just blank space.

Is there any other way of doing this or am i doing it right?

p.s: i can't use databases.

Comment: Cookies enabled in your browser you are testing from? Make sure PHPSESSID exists in your cookies, and that it is not changing between page requests (if it is, then something is breaking with the session).

Comment: Yes, cookies are enabled and my sessions ID is the same.

Comment: And you never return to `index.php` correct? You are only bouncing between `form.php` and `display.php` in the same session submitting multiple forms? All within the session timeout time so it does not time out?

Answer (score 0):

Not surprisingly, you have a new `$_SESSION` for each session, so stocking any information that way won't work.

If you want to persist data across sessions, you have to persist it somewhere. Consider writing it to a file if you can't use databases, for example.

Comment: I have the same session ID in the test, i just change the '$_SESSION index', is that wrong? Sorry, i couldn't understand.

Comment: I think he means if the session times out (user is gone for too long, and thus starts a new session). Or if multiple users come in, they wont be sharing the session and same data in the session. Its a per-user, per session (typically 20 minutes).